# Programmatic layout : UIStackView alignment doesn't seem to work

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I have created a `UIViewController` with a `UIStackView` (vertical axis) wrapped in a `UIScrollView` that's pinned to the edges of the root `View` with auto-layout constraints.

I have also generated a number of `UIButton`s and added to the `arranged subviews` of the `UIStackView`.

I have tried to no avail to centre align the `UIButtons` in the `UIStackView`.

I'm not certain what i'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var stackView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))


    stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .Vertical
    stackView.alignment = .Center
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    for _ in 1 ..< 100 {
        let vw = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        vw.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extra equal width constraint between the `scrollView` and the `stackView` was needed. Like this:

```
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[stackView(==scrollView)]", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView, "scrollView": scrollView]))
```

That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
stackView.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
```

?

Comment: I already did that. I'm assuming there's something i'm doing wrong.